# Symbol denoting an element that is not in a set?

Tags: notation

When solving mathematical tasks it is often convenient to say something like:

> Let $\#$ be an arbitrary element that is not present in set $X$

or

> Let $\$$ be an arbitrary letter outside of alphabet $\mathcal{A}$

etc, etc. (Often because we will next construct a set / alphabet / algebra / whatever that is similar to the 'previous' one, but contains one more 'special' element).

I now have a problem because both $\#$ and $\$$ are used. Which other symbols are commonly used for this purpose?

I thought about $\bot$, but [having read Wikipedia entry about this symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_tack) I suppose I shouldn't use it unless I can show how my 'arbitrary element' translates to the notion of absurdum.

Besides indexing - can I ask for a list of symbols I may safely use for this purpose?

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/157904/214697) proposes $\infty$ - but I must say this confuses me, because I've always associated this symbol to the notion of infinity.

Or would it be acceptable to invent my own symbols?

> Let [image] be an arbitrary element not included by the carrier of algebra $A$

<sub>I understand that the problem is rather minor and the points for an exam will likely not depend on this - but if I can improve, however slightly, the quality of my homework by not violating conventions and using symbols within their accepted meanings, then why not?</sub>

Comment: How about a Greek letter? Personally I would avoid inventing symbols just because that will make typesetting difficult.

Comment: I'm not sure that I see why you require a special symbol.  What is wrong with just saying "Let $x \in A^{\complement}$" or "Suppose $x\not\in A$"?

Comment: @XanderHenderson they have an alphabet they're working over and want to introduce a new symbol that has not been used. The title isn't great.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I have a set $X$ , I suppose $x$ would mean 'an element from $X$' - perhaps I'm nitpicking though. $y$ will do I guess?

Comment: If you have decided that $x\in X$, why not decorate an $x$ to denote something not in $X$?  For example, $\overline{x}, \dot{x}, \hat{x}, \tilde{x}, \dotsc$

Comment: In any event, if it were my own work, I would want very much to stay away from strange symbols, such as $\#$ or $\$$.  The $\#$ symbol is often used to denote the cardinality of a set, and can also be used as a binary operator (I have a vague memory of this showing up somewhere in some topology class I took once).  I would strongly recommend the use of some letter-like symbol.  A Roman letter, perhaps in a different font or with decoration, or a Greek letter.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Oddly enough, $\$$ and $\#$ were often used by profs on blackboards and in scripts for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

"Let  $☺️ \not\in X$."?  Works right up until your sets implement Unicode.

Upon consideration, although you haven't said as much, perhaps what you are really needing is a way to distinguish symbols in a language and symbols in a theory about that language.  (This is a fairly common problem in formal language theory.)  One method is to use the typographical convention you are already using.  "$1$", "$2$", et c. are symbols in the language of arithmetic and they are not italicized.  In fact, in proper style, we should never italicize *constants*, including $\pi$ and $\mathrm{e}$.  (And, yes, I know *that* "$\pi$" is italicized and yes, I realize it is far too late to make Computer Modern Roman default to non-italic pi so that all of its typographical descendants can instead do the correct thing here.)  So I recommend the same thing here.  The set of your alphabet can be $X = \left\{ \mathrm{a}, \mathrm{b}, \mathrm{c}, \dots, \mathrm{z}, \mathrm{A}, \mathrm{B}, \dots, \mathrm{Z}, \dots \right\}$ and then continue using italics for symbols in the meta-language.  E.g., $x \not \in X$.

Comment: ... and if the OP can include a graphic doodle to represent an element (with colors?), well, then the number of such elements is extraordinarily large.  Oh... and arbitrary strings of characters:   $\alpha a \zeta \Gamma \notin {\cal A}$...  And then there are subscripts... and superscripts...  and bold...

Comment: Italic vs not italic is a little hard to distinguish, though your explanation actually clarifies the question a lot, I think.  What about $\mathsf{X} = \{\mathsf{a,b,c,\dotsc,x,y,z,A,B,C,\dotsc}\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $e$ be an arbitrary element that is not present in set $X$.

Let $l$ be an arbitrary letter outside of alphabet $\mathcal{A}$.

If all letters are already reserved (?):

Let $e^*$ be an arbitrary element that is not present in set $X$.

Let $l^*$ be an arbitrary letter outside of alphabet $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: $e$ is 2.71... $l*$ means letter $l$ repeated arbitrarily many times... OK I guess this mindset of mine will not lead me anywhere, if I'm hellbent to look for conflicts I will always find them. Your suggestions are fine, I guess - simplest solutions work wonders.

Comment: @gaazkam: the key point is that if you state what the symbol is, there is no ambiguity. If you are really willing to draw special attention and visually distinguish the elements and non-elements, you can use all typographical tricks such as indices, exponents, over- and underlines, italics, bold or whatever.

Comment: @gaazkam: by the way, I did not particularly recommend the letters $e$ nor $l$. Just an example.